# either or fields django models

Tags: django, django-models

Hi i am creating a django model for a type of subscription for books

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True, blank=True)
    book_list = models.ForeignKey(Books, null=True)

    def create(cls, (user, group), **kwds):
        return cls(user=user, group=group, books=books, **kwds)
```

I want to create this in such a way that either the field user is chosen or the field Group but not both
the above syntax gives an error " User object not iterable"
can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing if you wish to create as such, one suggestion would be add a Manager to this model, for eg. SubscriptionManager and in that write create method. It could be something like this.

```
def create(self, subscriber, **kwds):
    if isinstance(subscriber, User):
       #save subscriber instance in user field
    elif isinstance(subsriber, Group):
       #save subscriber instance is group field
```

**PS: I have only provided solution for either or question, take care of books_list as well**